# Accessing git to install mysql on server on gandi.net

Tags: mysql, node.js, git, ssh

I purchased a Simple Hosting instance using node.js/mysql on gandi.net.

I'm trying to set up my database, but I'm having some issues with connectivity.

I found some sample code to connect and talk to the database (which I set up via PHPMyAdmin), but it requires the mysql module (which I assumed would already be installed on my instance, but since I don't know how any of this works, that's fine).

I get the error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'

in my log file.

I'm at a loss though as to how to actually install the module.

I tried to use their SSH console (via a firefox plugin), but my SSH credentials don't have the permission to run 'npm install mysql' and sudo isn't installed.

I also tried to install Git for Windows from mysisgit but I have zero idea how to connect to my remote server from this tool.

I'm just looking for some advice on how to proceed. I'm totally new and am engaging in learning this for personal development, so I don't have a lot of info on where to turn. Thanks!

Comment: As a workaround you could install the `mysql` module locally, then copy your `node_modules` directory over to your hosting.

Comment: That's a great idea! (And I already "accidentally" installed it locally, so I have the folders ready to sftp.) Only question is 'where' in the file structure this module should go? (I'm super new, and there are a lot of folders in my lamp stack!)

Comment: You just copy it to the same directory where your node app is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't using SSH to install to the correct directory (I was just trying to run it directly when I logged into shell). I needed to navigate into my web/vhosts/default/ directory, then the 'npm install mysql' worked absolutely fine.